# Confusing variable export failure in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, meteor, typescript, babeljs

I'm in the process of converting a Meteor application from TypeScript to Javascript. On the server side, I'm having some issues with `import`/`export` code that worked in TypeScript and seem to not work in Javascript. I've added a .babelrc (below), and I assumed (apparently incorrectly) that Meteor/Babel would transpile the `import`/`export` to work in NodeJS.

Stepping through the code in WebStorm my exports appear to be undefined when I import them:

```
// MyModule.js
export var my_var = new MyObj();
module.exports.my_var = my_var;  // Previous line isn't working, let's try ES5-style

// main.js
var MyModule = require("./MyModule");
// Why is MyModule is undefined here?!

import {my_var} from "./MyModule";
// Why is my_var is undefined here?!
```

In case it matters, my .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [ "meteor", "es2015", "stage-0" ],
  "plugins": ["transform-flow-strip-types"]
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? How do I properly import `my_var`?

Comment: What about `var MyModule = require("./MyModule");`?

Comment: Sorry I stripped the path as part of anonymizing the code, it's actually a proper relative path in my code. I will edit the question to reflect this

Comment: node.js does not yet support `import` and `export` keywords so you can give up on those. You can read a discussion about doing so in a future version of node.js here: https://nodesource.com/blog/es-modules-and-node-js-hard-choices/

Comment: These files were previously in TypeScript, and I'm in the process of converting them to regular JS. The imports/exports worked fine in TS, so I was assuming (apparently incorrectly) that babel would transpile the imports/exports to work correctly in JS as well

Comment: I can't speak for Babel on that topic.  I didn't know either TypeScript or Babel was involved here.  Perhaps you should add some appropriate tags or text explanation to indicate that and describe your particular goal with regard to taht.  I see the reference to .babelrc, but that's a bit subtle as to what your intentions are here.

Comment: Thanks, I added more details and tags

Comment: There certainly is import/export support in Babel.  See https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#modules and http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/babel-commonjs.html

Comment: Try changing instead of var --> const.

Comment: @DiegoGallegos: That wouldn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works as expected

### MyModule.js

```
function MyObj() {}
export var my_var = new MyObj();
exports.my_var2 = my_var;
```

### main.js

```
var myModule = require('./mod');
console.log('requiring', myModule);

import {my_var} from './mod';
console.log('importing', my_var);
```

### output

```
#dont forget npm install babel-preset-es2015
❯ babel-node --presets es2015 main.js
requiring { my_var: MyObj {}, my_var2: MyObj {} }
importing MyObj {}
```

Answer (score 0):

After digging deeper, it appears to have been a caching problem. Following the instructions in https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5328 to delete the meteor cache directories fixed the issue